# Swap switch rearrange workspaces by hotkey?

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, mate, ubuntu-mate, productivity

### Known stuff:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>left-arror</kbd> moves to the previous workspace. (i.e., `WS2 -> WS1`)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>right-arrow</kbd> moves to the next workspace (i.e., `WS1 -> WS2`).

But swapping workspaces isn't so easily referenced!

### Issue:

I made a mistake!  WS3 should be WS2!   WS2 should be WS3!

### Questions by value:

1. How to rearrange workspaces via keyboard?
2. How to rearrange workspaces?
3. How to clone a workspace [via keyboard]?

### Terribly cumbersome workaround:

<kbd>right-click</kbd> ***every*** proggy/app taskbar-item in both WSs and ***click*** <kbd>Move to Another Workspace</kbd>

### Slightly better workaround:

1. <kbd>mod</kbd>: launcher.
2. <kbd>Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>.
3. Change <kbd>Switch to workspace #</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>mod</kbd> + <kbd>num #</kbd>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are additional shortcut keys that can be added.

Comment: You might want to include the steps to add additional shortcuts to make this a rock solid answer.